# Is anyone else experiencing keys (I am not touching) being sent to WSL 2 gui apps and how should I report it to Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider

I am trying the Windows insider preview 10.0.21.390.1000 (co_release) with Ubuntu 18.0.4 (and Ubuntu 20.0.4) under WSL 2 to use Emacs in GUI mode without needing VcXsrv.  With either version I sometimes (not always) experience the following "glitch".  Emacs starts receiving a repeated key even though I am not touching the keyboard nor the mouse (often starting just as I bring the distribution up; bringing up emacs is the main thing I go into Linux for and the main reason I use the computer at all).  The key is usually C-c (control c), but is sometimes just c and sometimes " " (space).  It happens with both versions of Ubunutu, so it isn't specific to one of them.

I also have Ubuntu (18.0.4) under WSL 1 with VcXsrv and it doesn't experience this issue.  So, I am assuming that it is somehow WSL 2 related and possibly related to that release.

Any ideas on the cause and more importantly how should I report this issue to Microsoft.  I've never beta tested anything as an external user before.

Note:  It appears to only happen when I open the distribution after I have successfully started emacs once before.

Comment: I have this occur as well.  I wonder if it has something to do with how emacs quits.  Specifically, I notice when I start emacs after closing out of it with C-x C-c or SPC q q (my binding), it repeats the last key pressed: C-c or q.  I am going to look into how emacs exits a process and see if that is related.

Comment: I also experience this with WSL2 on Windows11. Hitting the key that is getting repeated clears it up, but this occurs in places where the last character typed was <CR>, or otherwise something that is a shortcut for a GUI element in a dialog that pops up.,  The repeated character does not appear to always be the last key I pressed, so I wonder if there is an uninitialized variable or structure field that is getting interpreted as a "make" scan-code by the virtualization of the keyboard into wayland (via dbus?).  I have experienced this with emacs, Tcl/Tk dialogs, synaptic, and others.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this is a known issue and will eventually be fixed; see https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/207